# System randomly freezes yet mouse still moves, SSD out of reallocatable sectors, should I replace it?

Tags: windows, ssd, freeze, crash, sectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it really possible to repair bad sectors?](https://superuser.com/questions/194220/is-it-really-possible-to-repair-bad-sectors)

This problem has lasted for the past 48 hours.  The first time it happened, a program I was running stopped responding, so I tried to end it from task manager.  The processes at first were listed fine until hovered upon.  Eventually, despite the mouse still being able to move, after a few persisting clicks the mouse finally stopped moving.  The screen went blank shortly thereafter.

The second time it occurred, items on the screen stopped responding - hovering over the taskbar or such wouldn't elicit a response.  Sound would still play however.  Eventually, the mouse became unresponsive and the system restarted itself.

I suspect that it may be a problem of my SSD drive.  After looking through some Google search results, I downloaded HDTunePro to determine if there's a problem with the drive.  Results returned a problem of reallocated sector count.  An error scan also revealed 48 bad sectors.

Also, an attempt to backup the contents of the most important areas of the drive returned a few explorer "Error: cannot read source from disk" errors.

Should I ditch the drive and use another drive or is there anything that can be done to repair the drive?

SSD: OCZ Petrol 64gb
CPU: AMD Athlon II X4 640
RAM: Generic 3GB DDR2
Motherboard: Gigabyte MA74GM-S2H
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Thanks!

Comment: The error is probably that you're out of reallocatable sector space, so any further bad sectors will just remain 'bad' and not be reallocated.  Short form: it's bad, replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the SSD and use a partion tool to recover and copy the partion and data to a HDD. I believe your assumtion correct that the SSD is the point of your issue and you may find that the realocated sector count will begin to grow.